# Displaying list of items. In my case list of users

Tags: asp.net, list, asp.net-mvc-3

I have been trying to list all the users in my database but I am having a hard time. I am new to MVC3 pls help. :)

This is my UserList

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using MVCDemo.Models.DB;
using MVCDemo.Models.ViewModel;

namespace MVCDemo.Models.ViewModel
{


    public class UserList
    {

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

     }

    public class Users
    {
        private DeveloperReportEntities dre = new DeveloperReportEntities();
        public UserList _userList = new UserList();


        public Users()
        {
            DB.Users_Tbl userTBL = new DB.Users_Tbl();
            _userList.FirstName = userTBL.FirstName;
            _userList.LastName = userTBL.LastName;
            _userList.Email = userTBL.Email;
            _userList.Address = userTBL.Address;
            _userList.ContactNumber = userTBL.ContactNo;
            _userList.Username = userTBL.Username;
            _userList.Password = userTBL.Password;
         }


    }
}
```

which is supposed to be controlled through here: AdminController

```
    public class AdminController : Controller
    {
        //
         // GET: /Admin/

        public ActionResult AdminHomePage()
        {
             return View();
        }

        public ActionResult ViewAll()
         {
            return View();
         }
     }
```

in my solution explorer i have a samplemodel.edmx in model folder

Comment: In your ViewAll action method, you have not called Users class constructor. So, if you want to store those details you need to create the object for Users class and inoder to save changes to database you need to call context.SaveChanges (); method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the `Users` class should encapsulate a `List` of `User`. Here's what it should look like:

**/Controllers/Admin/AdminController.cs**

```
public class User
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set }
}

public class AdminController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Admin/
    public ActionResult AdminHomePage()
    {
         return View();
    }

    public ActionResult ViewAll()
    {
        var userTBL = new DB.Users_Tbl();
        var users = userTBL.Select(u => new User { FirstName = u.FirstName, LastName = u.LastName };
        return View(users);
    }
 }
```

**/Views/Admin/ViewAll.cshtml**

```
@model List<User>
<ul>
@foreach(var user in Model)
{
   <li>@user.FirstName @user.LastName</li>
}
</ul>
```